# Setting an Infopath default value for Edit view

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I've got a list with some repeating data, which is based on this tutorial http://salnikan.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/inserting-multiple-list-items-at-once-into-a-sharepoint-list/. Basically, the user picks an ID from a drop down list (tempID) which is then replicated into the repeating main data source using default value = tempID. This works great, but I've created an edit view which I want to pick up what is in the list and allow the user to change if necessary. How can I do that? Currently it's a null value, because tempID doesn't appear in the edit form (and if it did it'd still be null unless the user picked the ID again).

using infopath 2010 & sharepoint 2010 standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not possible. I've had to settle for creating a button with a rule that updates the fields on the form with the data in the list.